# How to replace System.FormatException

Tags: c#, exception

I'm currently learning c# and trying to make a simple calculation app. When the user inputs a letter instead of a number, this exception is thrown. How do I handle it so that instead of this, I can output "invalid" and allow the user to try again?

I've been looking at try-catch but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Use the `TryParse` methods on the number types like [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0), try-catch works fine and in the end it achieves the same as the `TryParse` method but personally I much prefer `TryParse`

Comment: @MindSwipe read [Vexing exceptions](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Would be helpful if you shared your code - then you can get a more tailored answer

Comment: Welcome to the site!  
This would be far easier to answer if we had a little more context - what input controls are you using? Is this a console application? Which method is throwing the exception? @MindSwipe is correct, however I'd like to raise the point that in a calculator you're most likely dealing with decimals, and a [Floating-Point numeric type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) would be more appropriate than `Int32`. @Zohar not sure on the relevance to mindswipe? Eric even lauds TryParse as the right way.

Comment: @ZoharPeled interesting read, thanks, IMO exceptions are exactly that, exceptional, so if you anticipate something can/ will throw an exception then it's not exceptional anymore and you should check the values beforehand.

Comment: @MindSwipe I agree. IMHO, catching exceptions should be almost exclusively used for things you can't control and / or can't test before using (What Mr. Lippert calls "exogenous exceptions"). i.e. a NullReferenceException or DivideByZeroException is not something you want to use try...catch for, however FileNotFoundException is something very useful.

Comment: @ZoharPeled IMO it extends further, a `FileNotFoundException` can easily be "mitigated" by just checking `File.Exists` beforehand, after that check you can safely assume the file exists, and if it disappears, for example a user deletes it halfway through processing, then you can throw the exception (i.e .NET throws it for you) because that is truly exceptional. But my opinion could easily be skewed by Rust, a language wholly without exceptions and where failures are baked into the type system.

Comment: @MindSwipe My point is that the file system is something that is out of your control, it could just as easily be something like remote communication or even database reads.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `decimal.TryParse` is what you'll want to use. If you're doing any form of division it'll get around the rounding issues involved with using an integer. ([see more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types))

```cs
public decimal?[] ConvertInputs(string[] inputs)
{//We're taking an array of inputs to make it easier for the calculator to perform compound expressions.
    if (inputs is null)
    {//This should never happen, don't try/catch this just prevent it.
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputs));
    }

    decimal?[] values = new decimal?[inputs.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = decimal.TryParse(inputs[i], out decimal value) ? value : null;
    }

    return values;
}
```

Then we'll use [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-7.0) to check for any inputs which weren't valid:

```cs
public void Calculate(string[] inputs)
{
    if (inputs is null)
    {//This should never happen, don't try/catch this just prevent it.
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputs));
    }

    decimal?[] values = this.ConvertInputs(inputs);
    if (values.Length == 0)
    {
         //user didn't give you any parameters, inform them of that!
         return;
    }  

    int errorIndex = Array.IndexOf(values, null);
    if (int != -1)//-1 is return for the value (in this case null) not being present.
    {
        string invalidInput = inputs[errorIndex];
        //tell the user this input was not valid.
        return;
    }

    //Do your calculation here. None of the values are null.
}
```

For a simpler quick and dirty way of doing this, see below.

```cs
public void Calculate(string inputA, string inputB)
{
    if (!decimal.TryParse(inputA, out valueA) || !decimal.TryParse(inputB, out valueB))
    {//tell your user something's invalid.
        return;
    }

    //Perform your calculation with valueA and valueB, they're both initialized.
}
```

Comment: Quick note: `Double` is not the same as `double`. Always prefer using the language keywords instead of class names from the System namespace. 
For more information, read [string vs. String is not a style debate](https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2019/04/08/string-vs-String-is-not-about-style.html)  by Jared Parsons

Comment: FWIW I'd use `decimal` and the accompanying [`decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-7.0) for a calculator (where precision is usually wanted)

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks! good info which I'll be using to push for changes to the Style Guide at my workplace. I've updated my answer to adjust for both of these addenda.

Comment: @MindSwipe also thank you, I don't know what I was thinking. Perhaps not enough caffeine this morning!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C#

To fix the error you should try to use `int.TryParse()` or `int.Parse()` methods. if you're using `float` or some other type to perform calculation actions, than change the `int` part with the type you use.

The `try-catch` block is a different story.

- [`try-catch` block documentation - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

For more detailed information about the `Parse()` and `TryParse()` methods, Visit the links shown below:

- [`Parse()` method documentation - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-7.0)
- [`TryParse()` Method documentation - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0)
- other sources - [TheDotnetGuide](https://thedotnetguide.com/tryparse-vs-parse-in-csharp/)

**So in short,Get to know these methods and you will find the solution very quickly for sure.**

Tip: If you are new to C# I'd recommend two places to learn it.

- [pluralsight.com](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/)
- [exercism.org](https://exercism.org/) - This one is free, plus you can learn lots of other programming languages.

Answer (score -1):

As some coments above said, there are some ways to handle it.

I also prefer to use `int.TryParse` in order to validate if the input is valid or not.

To summarize it.  I would do create  a method to wrap this validation:

```cs
public bool IsValidCalculationInput(string? inputA, string? inputB)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputA)) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputB)) return false;
    if (!inputA.TryParseInt(out _)) return false;
    if (!inputB.TryParseInt(out _)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Also I would create some extensions helping me handle this validations, in my case I've created a Class called IntegerExtensions:

```cs
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets generic type and implicit calls ToString()  method trying to convert a generic to int
    /// This methods doesnt throws exceptions and returns int.MinValue if conversion fails
    /// You can also force it to throw an exception by setting the throwException parameter to true
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be parsed</param>
    /// <param name="result">Parsed value</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Generic Type</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool TryParseInt<T>(this T value, out int result, bool throwException =false)
    {
        try
        {
            return int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (throwException) throw;
            result = Int32.MinValue;
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Explicit calls ToString()  method converting a generic to int throwing an exception if it fails
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int ToInt<T>(this T value)
    {
        return int.Parse(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

In the end I would call it like this:

```cs
public void Calculate(string? inputA, string? inputB)
{
    if (!IsValidCalculationInput(inputA, inputB))
    {
        // Here you can handle the invalid result and return an class/throw an exception, it's your call.
        // In this case my method returns void, so I just return.
        return;
    }

    var parsedInputA = inputA.ToInt();
    var parsedInputB = inputB.ToInt();
    // Do the calculation
    // return parsedInputA + parsedInputB;

}
```

## **EDITS**

I'm updating the IsValidCalculationInput to achive some improvements suggested in comments:

Now it will receive **N** parameters than it will return if the whole list of parameters is valid for calculation.

```cs
bool IsValidCalculationInput(out int?[] outputs,params string?[] inputs)
{
    outputs = new int?[inputs.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputs[i]) || !int.TryParse(inputs[i], out var parsedInput))
        {
            outputs[i] = null;
            return false;
        }

        outputs[i] = parsedInput;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
void Calculate(string inputA, string? inputB)
{
    if (!IsValidCalculationInput(out var inputsParsed,inputA, inputB))
    {
        // Here you can handle the invalid result and return an class/throw an exception, it's your call.
        // In this case my method returns void, so I just return.
        return;
    }
    
    // Do the calculation
    // return parsedInputA + parsedInputB;
    var result = 0;
    foreach (var input in inputsParsed)
        result = result + input.Value;

}
```

Comment: This works, but I'd be hesitant to use integers for a calculator.

Comment: That's an awful lot of work to do a worst job than what you get out of the box from the framework.

Comment: Spend one minute writing this code. Don't think it's a lot of work. And It's very hard to make and app that just calculate a thing. 
As the system grows it's important to have things like that to help.

Comment: Also, you're duplicating the workload for the function, not a big deal here but as scope grows this would be very wasteful. Might be better to take perhaps an array of strings as input and return an array of nullable integers, then check for a null value in the result. Also, strings are already nullable as a reference type and you definitely don't want them to be null, so marking them nullable is not appropriate.

Comment: Sure I could do a lot of other things differently too, but for the problem presented I still would do the same that I've suggested here.  This is just my way to handle it, please provide another and I'll be glad to up vote it =)

Comment: "Spent one minute writing this code" -> will spend a lot of time in the future reading it. Also, as @TheHitchenator wrote - you're parsing each string twice. This is probably not a problem in this case but can be problematic in other situations.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback guys. Please, provide the best way doing that so we can close this topic.

Comment: The best way would probably be to just use `int.TryParse` once for each string.

Comment: The whole point of `TryParse` is to not throw exceptions - literally - but you've written code specifically to re-introduce them. Please don't use this code.

Comment: Where? As far i remember it's an optional parameter in the created extension that is set to false, so if not passed will not throw any exception. Alson in my Edits i'm not using the extension.